# Why doesn't my NSOutputStream have space available after the first write? (hasSpaceAvailable becomes NO)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

With NSOutputStream I get to write perfectly just the first time.

Here is the method to send data:

```
- (NSInteger)sendVsCommand:(VsCommand *)command
{
    NSData *commandArray = [NSData dataWithData:[command getCommandArray]];
    NSLog(@"Space availiable: %d", [writeStream hasSpaceAvailable]);
    NSInteger result = [writeStream write:[commandArray bytes] 
                                maxLength:[commandArray length]];
    NSLog(@"Writing result: %d", result);
    return result;
}
```

And here is the handling of the events:

```
case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            NSLog(@"%@ can accept bytes", aStream);
            if (aStream == writeStream) {
                NSLog(@"Can send data: %d", [writeStream hasSpaceAvailable]);
            }
            break;
```

Just the 'case' that matters anyway.

Here are the results in the console:

```
2013-08-16 18:07:12.769 hMonitor[5765:307] <__NSCFInputStream: 0x148650> is open
2013-08-16 18:07:12.776 hMonitor[5765:307] <__NSCFOutputStream: 0x148330> is open
2013-08-16 18:07:12.777 hMonitor[5765:307] <__NSCFOutputStream: 0x148330> can accept bytes
2013-08-16 18:07:12.779 hMonitor[5765:307] Can send data: 1
2013-08-16 18:07:13.107 hMonitor[5765:307] <__NSCFInputStream: 0x148650> has bytes
2013-08-16 18:07:13.112 hMonitor[5765:307] Space availiable: 1
2013-08-16 18:07:13.116 hMonitor[5765:307] Writing result: 41
2013-08-16 18:07:13.118 hMonitor[5765:307] <__NSCFOutputStream: 0x148330> can accept bytes
2013-08-16 18:07:13.119 hMonitor[5765:307] Can send data: 1
2013-08-16 18:07:13.687 hMonitor[5765:307] <__NSCFInputStream: 0x148650> has bytes
2013-08-16 18:07:15.343 hMonitor[5765:307] Space availiable: 0
2013-08-16 18:07:15.345 hMonitor[5765:307] Writing result: 0
```

1. As you can see, when the streams open, I can write just fine (Can
   send data: 1).
2. Then I receive some data, and write a response immediately, Space
   availiable: 1 and Writing result: 41.
3. Almost immediately the OutputStream is free to write again, Can send
   data: 1 (but I don't need to send anything, until the user makes
   some selection). And I get a response very quickly.
4. Finally, I try to write again (2 seconds later because that's when
   the user has made a selection). However, now the Space available is
   NO, and the Writing result is 0.

Any ideas? Where do you recommend I should look?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens during those 2 seconds? Does the stream still exist afterwards?

Comment: Is it scheduled?   Has the other end closed it?   Are any of the other cases in the switch statement being fired?

Comment: They are nil! :O Weird, because I did not receive a EndEncountered event...

Answer (score 0):

My pointers were becoming nil, because I was not handling them the right way.

Just goes to show how green I am in Objective-C.